Does there exist a continous function for which there is no continuous choice for $\delta$ provided an $\epsilon$?
We say that a function has the property of having continuous choice of $\delta$ provided $\epsilon$ for each point in it's domain, if there is an assignment of $\delta$ for each provided $\epsilon$ such that this assignment is sufficient to satisfy the criterion of epsilon delta and further that the assignment regarded as a map is continous.
Example of such a function is $x^2$, we have this following assignment of $\delta$ given an $\epsilon$ that satisfies the criterion:
$$\delta = \min\left(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{2|x_0| + 1}\right)$$
In the above $\delta(\epsilon)$ is a continuous as a function of $\epsilon$ for a given point $x_0$. My question, does there exist a continuous function for which there can be no continous assignment of  $\delta$ for a given input of $\epsilon$? Further would this answer change if we saw $\delta$ rather as a multivariable function of $(x_0,\epsilon)$ and then pose this same but in view of it's multi variable continuity?

Note: No attempt as this question is completly outside of my weightclass. Nonetheless it is a curoisity of mine, and hope someone can show how one could possibly even try answering this.
$x^2$ continuity

"In the above $\delta(\epsilon)$ is a continuous as a function of $\epsilon$": rather $\delta(x_0,\epsilon)$ is a continuous function of $(x_0,\epsilon)$. Can you please precise your question accordingly?

Some ideas. If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at only one point and not elsewhere, then the result should easily be false. Suppose from now on that $f$ is continuous everywhere. We focus on non-decreasing $\delta$. If $\delta$ is discontinuous at $\epsilon_0$, then we will necessarily have a discontinuity at the values which $f$ attains $f(x) + \epsilon_0$ or $f(x) - \epsilon_0$.

Note that the maximum choice of $\delta(\epsilon)$ is monotonically increasing (with increasing $\epsilon$). So there can only be countably many discontinuities. So all you need is to smooth out the function around these points, which should always be possible since you can at any point decrease the value of $\delta(\epsilon)$ without it being a problem

@AnneBauval Would this distinction have an effect on the positivty of the statement? It didn't even occur to me that it should. Altho arbitary, I make now specific in the question that I am interested in continuity of it seen as a function of $\epsilon$ with $x_o$ constant

For any continuous $f$, $\delta$ can indeed be chosen continuously as a function of $\epsilon$ and $x$. This holds not just for functions $f\!:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ but even if the domain and range of $f$ are arbitrary metric spaces.
This was first shown by Ali Enayat,

MR1745893 (2000m:54014). Enayat, Ali. $\delta$ as a continuous function of $x$ and $\epsilon$. Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 2, 151–155.

For a somewhat simpler argument than Ali's see

MR1837868. De Marco, Giuseppe. For every $\epsilon$ there continuously exists a $\delta$. Amer. Math. Monthly 108 (2001), no. 5, 443–444.


Great references

We can actually rephrase the question the following way:
Given an increasing (not necessarily strictly) function $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$, can we find a continuous function $g$ with the same domain and codomain such that $g(x) \leq f(x)$ for all points.
The answer is yes. Let $c_n$ stand for the infimum of $f$ in the region $[\frac{1}{n},\infty)$. Now, in the domain $[1,\infty)$, $g$ will just be the constant $c_2$ (not $c_1$, because that would screw with the next step).
In the remaining part of the domain, $(0,1)$, we will paste linear functions on $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ together such that $g(\frac{1}{n}) = c_{n+1}$ for all $n$. This will be below $f$ by construction, and continuous by the pasting lemma.
Edit: While I use this implicitly, I'll state it explicitly here: the infimum exists, and is just equal to $f(\frac{1}{n})$ because $f$ is increasing. Otherwise, the proof would not work.

Potential worry that the infimum is $0$ but in this case $c_n = f(1/n) > 0$. Otherwise this would work for any function.

Nice answer. "Let $c_n$ stand for the infimum of $f$ in the region $\left[ \frac{1}{n}, \infty \right)$"... since we know that $f$ is increasing (even if not necessarily strictly), do we not just have $c_n = f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$?

True for both responses. I was in a hurry writing this trying to be the first to respond :)
I'll edit to iron out the kinks.

It took me a while to see that $f$ is not required to be continuous. Maybe you could emphasize this in your answer.

Can we even make $g$ an analytic function?

We can construct $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=0$. Indeed, instead of $g(\tfrac1n)=f(\tfrac1{n+1})$, we can define $g(\tfrac1n)=\tfrac1n f(\tfrac1{n+1})$.

This is not an answer to the question you asked but a commentary on the example of $f(x) = x^2$. Let's first write down what condition is being asked for here. $f(x)$ satisfies the epsilon-delta definition of continuity at $x = a$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta(\varepsilon)$ such that
$$|x - a| < \delta(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon.$$
Your example of $f(x) = x^2$ generalizes to the following. If $f(x)$ is not only continuous but differentiable, then by the mean value theorem there exists $c$ between $x$ and $a$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| = |x - a| |f'(c)|$; in other words the absolute value of the derivative $|f'|$ between $x$ and $a$ controls how much larger $|f(x) - f(a)|$ can get than $|x - a|$. If $f'(x)$ is also assumed to be continuous this implies that we can take, roughly speaking,
$$\delta(\varepsilon) \approx \frac{\varepsilon}{|f'(a)| + 1}$$
for $\varepsilon$ small (and $\varepsilon$ large doesn't matter). The $+1$ is just a little fudge to handle the case that $f'(a) = 0$. A more careful version of this bound can be written down but hopefully this conveys the idea. So if $f$ is continuously differentiable $\delta(\varepsilon)$ can be made continuous in both $\varepsilon$ and $a$.
