Does there exist a continuous witness for continuity?
Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subset. Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous at $x_0 \in I$. Is there some continuous(!) function $\delta : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that
$|x-x_0| \leq \delta(\varepsilon) \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq \varepsilon$
for all $\varepsilon> 0$? In other words, is there a "continuous witness for continuity" of $f$ at $x_0$?
In many examples, I was able to find one. For example, for $f(x) = x^2$ and $x_0 \neq 0$ we may choose $\delta(\varepsilon) = \min(\sqrt{\varepsilon/3},\varepsilon/(3 |x_0|))$; for $x_0=0$ we omit the bad fraction. The usual operations of continuous functions extend to their witnesses of continuity, so that here continuity of them also is preserved.

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4953826/does-there-exist-a-continous-function-for-which-there-is-no-continuous-choice-fo?rq=1

Is this not answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4953826/does-there-exist-a-continous-function-for-which-there-is-no-continuous-choice-fo ?

Thanks! Let us close this as a duplicate then.
